# I have a problem in POST method in python

Tags: python, django, post

I am using windows(10) and django library I wanted to make sign up option in my e-commerce so I made an app called accounts, I wrote in its views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    print('In Post')
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        print(username , password)

else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request , 'registration/signup.html' , context)
```

And I wrote in my signup.html page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
<main class="mt-5">
    <div class="container mynav">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock body %}
```

The problem in the POST method when I tried to run it he said
`The view accounts.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`
In CMD(=terminal) `The User could not be created because the data didn't validate.`
What do I write to solve this problem? And Thanks.

Comment: You have to return something when `POST`. Your function just returns on `GET`.

Comment: So what do I do?